# How to get disjunction from datetime intervals using java 8

Tags: java, datetime, lambda, java-8, intervals

I have two `DateTime` interval lists and I want to get the disjunction of these ones. Does anyone know how could it be calculated?

Each interval is saved as an object:

```
public class Interval {
    LocalDateTime start;
    LocalDateTime end;
}
```

For example I have:

```
List<Interval> list1 >> [from 10:00 to 12:00] and [from 13:00 to 14:00]
List<Interval> list2 >> [from 10:00 to 11:00] and [from 13:30 to 14:00]
```

The result that I want to get is the intervals where they don't overlap:

```
List<Interval> result >> [from 11:00 to 12:00] and [from 13:00 to 13:30]
```

Comment: Example inputs and outputs would help.

Comment: So, you have the same number of intervals in both lists, and you want to subtract list2[i] from list1[i]? is that what you want? What if list2[0] is 10:30-11:30? Should the result contain 3 intervals?

Comment: Yes, I want to substract list2 from list1 and there are cases where I don´t have the same number of intervals but second list is always composes of subintervals of first list.

Comment: OK. The what should be the result is list1 has more elements than list2? And vice-versa? And if list2[0] is 10:30-11:30 (which *is* a subinterval of list1[0]? And of course, what have you tried?

Comment: Intervals included in list 2 can´t be outside of intervals included in list 1.

Comment: What I have tried is:

List result = list1 ;
for each interval within list 1 {
   for each interval within list 2 {
      if (isOverlapping) {
         remove interval from result list;
         include the rest from interval 1 that is not included in interval 2;
      }
  }
}

But this solution takes longer and I would like to find a better solution

Comment: 10:30-11:30 is NOT outside of 10:00-12:00. And you haen't answered the other questions either. Edit your question, and post all this missing information, including your attempt and the problem you faced.

Comment: If I have 10:30 to 11:30 the result that I expect is [from 10:00 to 10:30]  and [from 11:30 to 12:00]

Answer (score 3):

Either you can do it all manually, or you can use my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) and study this example taking your input which yields the expected output. As far as I have understood you correctly, you are looking for a [minus-operation](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IntervalCollection.html#minus-java.util.List-), i.e. subtracting one list of intervals from another one:

```
// first collect the intervals from "list1" into an IntervalCollection
TimestampInterval i1 =
    TimestampInterval.between(
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 10, 0),
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 12, 0));
TimestampInterval i2 =
    TimestampInterval.between(
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 13, 0),
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 14, 0));
IntervalCollection<PlainTimestamp> ic =
    IntervalCollection.onTimestampAxis().plus(Arrays.asList(i1, i2));

// then collect the intervals from "list2" as simple interval list
TimestampInterval j1 =
    TimestampInterval.between(
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 10, 0),
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 11, 0));
TimestampInterval j2 =
    TimestampInterval.between(
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 13, 30),
        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 9, 14, 0));

// finally perform the minus-operation
List<ChronoInterval<PlainTimestamp>> result = ic.minus(Arrays.asList(j1, j2)).getIntervals();

System.out.println(result);
// output: [[2017-09-09T11/2017-09-09T12), [2017-09-09T13/2017-09-09T13:30)]

// Alternative to get back `LocalDateTime`-objects for start (inclusive) and end (exclusive):
for (ChronoInterval<PlainTimestamp> interval : result) {
    LocalDateTime start = interval.getStart().getTemporal().toTemporalAccessor();
    LocalDateTime end = interval.getEnd().getTemporal().toTemporalAccessor();
    System.out.println(start + "/" + end);
}
```